# Generalization in fully dressed use case

Tags: uml, use-case

A generalization is shown in a use case diagram as seen in the picture below. I think this is a bad example but let us assume that local call and long-distance call each take 10 steps in a fully dressed use case. Half of the steps are the same, the other half are (slightly) different.

[diagram http://www.wthreex.com/rup/smallprojects/rup/guidances/guidelines/resources/ucgen4.gif](http://www.wthreex.com/rup/smallprojects/rup/guidances/guidelines/resources/ucgen4.gif)

My question is, how would we show this diagram in fully dressed use cases? I think the following, please correct me if I'm wrong:

```
Place call
1. do something that is the same for both children (ex. pick up phone)
2. do something that is the same for both children
3. do something that is the same for both children
4. do something that is different for both children but write it very abstract 
   so that it applies to both. (ex. make  a connection to the grid)
5. do something that is different for both children but write it very abstract
6. do something that is the same for both children
7. do something that is different for both children but write it very abstract
8. do something that is the same for both children
9. do something that is different for both children but write it very abstract
10. do something that is different for both children but write it very abstract


Place local call
1. rewrite the steps that are the same as the parent.
2.
3.
4. do something that is different for both children and write it detailed 
   (ex. make  a connection to the LOCAL grid)
...
```

Second question is: do you connect the primary actor with place call or with each child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question: I'd use the textual description of the respective use cases to outline said details or (as an alternative) write a scenario instead - or (as another alternative) use an activity diagram.

I'd consider it overkill to put it all in the use case diagram as it would be too detailed.

Second question: Connect it with `place call`. After all that is one of the important benefits of using generalizations.